# How can I echo "pass" or "fail" after a bash, curl, grep sequence?

Tags: bash, macos, curl, sed, grep

I'm big fan of elegant one-liners. I am trying to write a one-line test that outputs "pass" or "fail" after doing an http request and a search. I've tried something like this:

```
curl "http://haystack.io" | sed 's/.*?needle.*/PASS/' || echo FAIL
```

...but this doesn't fail properly.

Also tried:

```
curl "http://haystack.io" | if [$(grep -oE "needle") = "needle"]; then echo PASS; else echo FAIL; fi
```

...but I can't get the syntax quite right.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend -- as a rule, fixing the bugs it finds is a good place to start.

Comment: BTW, using `?` to modify whether a preceding `*` is greedy is a PCREism; it's not available in either BRE (which every POSIX-compliant `sed` uses by default) or ERE (which can be enabled in GNU or BSD `sed` with `-r` or `-E` arguments, respectively).

Comment: Try `curl "http://haystack.io" | grep -q needle && echo PASS || echo FAIL`. Caveat: `echo` may fail if stdout is not writable.

Comment: @alvits, grumble grumble, re: encouraging folks to treat `a && b || c` as the ternary that it's not. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I totally agree with you but I am not in any way encouraging the OP. My suggestion was merely to correct his failed attempt. Encouraging other readers is unintentional :(

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48535/can-grep-return-true-false-or-are-there-alternative-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just looking for the needle, you can use `grep -q` to get an exit code:

```
if curl "http://haystack.io" | grep -q needle
then
  echo "PASS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

---

The problem with your approach:

```
curl "http://haystack.io" | sed 's/.*?needle.*/PASS/' || echo FAIL
```

is that `sed` always returns success when the expression is valid, even when the replacement doesn't trigger. Plus, it uses BRE while your regex is PCRE.

In this one:

```
curl "http://haystack.io" | if [$(grep -oE "needle") = "needle"]; then echo PASS; else echo FAIL; fi
```

you're missing quotes and spacing ([shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) will help out with that), and it also doesn't work if there are multiple matches.

Comment: Thanks so much! I learned more about exit codes, bash redirection, and using the `echo $?` to find the exit code of the last command. Definitely need to learn more about the subtle differences in regexp flavors. :)